# Mapping values to other corresponding values

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with +400k rows of protein_protein interactions with Entrez identifiers, I want to map the identifiers to corresponding identifiers of different database Uniprot

database looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

and i want this

[image]

Provided that I have the corresponding values of each entrez id to uniprot id

[image]

Could you please suggest me an efficient way to do this, I can't think of anything other than iterating over the database

Comment: I don't follow the logic of your example.  I see proteinA_entrez and the lookup table to the uniprot_id, but then in the second screenshot the entrez_id is being matched to the proB_uniprot, why is it not matching with the proA_uniprot?

Comment: Do you just want column 1 of the first table to be combined with column 2 of the second table?

Comment: It's just an example i put together, i need to change data values using the 3rd table data

Comment: I don't understand how the first column of the middle table has anything to do with the other two tables.

Comment: middle table shows data mapped to the uniprot ids, the w wanted result

Comment: Where does the first column come from in the middle table?

Comment: both columns of middle table, are a result of matching the values of the 1st table to uniprot_id using the 3rd table

Comment: Should I change the example  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237229/discussion-between-danielschroederdev-and-hpph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this took me a minute to grok, but I think I have this for you. We discussed the example in chat, so you should probably update your question to reflect my answer since it varies from the original.

This is just iterating over the tables, so it's not a more efficient version, but I wasn't aware if you had anything at this point to start from, so at least this is something.

We're trying to create table2 from table1 and table3:

[image]

Starting with these CSV files:

*table1.csv*

```
paperA_db1,paperB_db1
9240,8601
8933,91289
```

*table3.csv*

```
paper_db1,paper_db2
9240,Q8ND90
8933,A6ZKI3
8601,O76081
91289,Q9BU23
```

We can do this using Python's `csv` module, like this:

```py
import csv

mappings = {}

with open("table3.csv", newline="") as mapping_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(mapping_csv)
    for row in reader:
        mappings[row["paper_db1"]] = row["paper_db2"]

table3 = {}

with open("table1.csv", newline="") as table1_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(table1_csv)
    for row in reader:
        table3[mappings[row["paperA_db1"]]] = mappings[row["paperB_db1"]]


with open("table2.csv", newline="", mode="w") as table2_csv:
    fieldnames = ['paperA_db2', 'paperB_db2']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(table2_csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for paperA_db2, paperB_db2 in table3.items():
        writer.writerow(dict(paperA_db2=paperA_db2, paperB_db2=paperB_db2))
```

Here's that running on my machine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mine is very similar to @DanielSchroederDev.
I've got a error check on the lookup, so the script keeps going.
I also just use a csv.reader rather than a csv.DictReader, 2 columns is pretty easy to keep in your head.
It also seems like overkill to use pandas, but if your data is in Excel, you'll need to uses a Excel reader, much easier to use text files, so save as csv!

```
import csv

trans = dict()
with open("key_file.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    next(c)
    for row in c:
        trans[row[0]] = row[1]
print(trans)


def lookup(p):
    try:
        return trans[p]
    except KeyError:
        print(f"No translation for {p}")
        return 0


with open("protiens.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    c = csv.reader(f)
    next(c)
    new_protiens = list(map(lambda x: [lookup(x[0]), lookup(x[1])], c))

print(new_protiens)

with open("translated.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    c.writerow(["proA_unipro", "proB_unipro"])
    for row in new_protiens:
        c.writerow(row)
```